# Docker: Docker-compose ruby + postgres - PG::ConnectionBadcould not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker

I created Dockerfile to ruby from [official docker-compose website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/). I used docker compose to integrate this with Postgres. When docker-compose up, then PostgreSQL starts but I cannot connect to this. The main problem is in ruby database config because I can't change to listen to another host and set the default user. I don't know how to connect these two containers without changing the ruby database config.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.3.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Ruby database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_development
```

If i run inside web conatiner "bundle exec rake db:create I get error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I don't know what env set that will connect together.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify database host in your `database.yml`. Set it to `db` or just try this database.yml

```
development: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: db

test:
  <<: *default
  database: project_test
```

Comment: I used similar database.yml and everything work, but I can't change database.yml. So this solution doesn't solve problem. I don't know what I must add to docker config, that will be help to connect.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It saved me a lot of stress. My `host` is `database` but I didn't have a `host` defined in my `database.yml` file. After defining it , everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should update your database.yml with the following:

```
  database: ENV['DB_NAME']
  username: ENV['DB_USERNAME']
  password: ENV['DB_PASSWORD']
```

There's no such thing as "default PG user", so you have to create your own user with a proper permissions.

So, once you have a PG user created inside of container, you can update your docker-compose.yml file with a proper DB settings:

```
web:
  environment:
    - DB_NAME=rails_development
    - DB_USERNAME=rails_user
    - DB_PASSWORD=rails_password
```

Also, you probably want to mount local storage of postgres in your docker-compose.yml to keep data when container restarts:

```
volumes:
  - /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: There is default user named `postgres` with empty password in docker images of postgres, so you don't have to create it. Your solution doesn't solve problem mentioned by author of question

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to [Bartosz Bonisławski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44902508/10907864).

I encountered this issue when building a **Rails** application on **Ubuntu** 18.04.

My `Dockerfile` for my `development` environment which was located in `docker/development/Dockerfile` directory of my project was defined like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/${RAILS_ENV}/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem-cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node-modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: ${RAILS_ENV}
      RACK_ENV: ${RACK_ENV}

  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    expose:
      - "5432"
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${DATABASE_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: ${DATABASE_HOST}

    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  gem-cache:
    driver: local
  node-modules:
    driver: local
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
```

While my `.env` file was defined as this:

```
DATABASE_USER=myapp_user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=myapp_password
DATABASE_NAME=myapp_development
DATABASE_HOST=database
DATABASE_PORT=5432

RAILS_ENV=development
RACK_ENV=development
```

The **issue** I had was that I did not add `host` config to my `database.yml` file of my project. So I was encountering the error:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
> Is the server running locally and accepting
> connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

**Here's how I solved**:

I simply added it like this and it worked perfectly fine:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DATABASE_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT'] %>
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**